# Updating redux state via props, how can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a react-redux library for data filtering. The way it basically works is by decorating your filter component so that it has access to the data to filter. The decorated component uses the library's `Filter` component. Here's roughly how it looks like:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    <Filter
        prop="propA" // What prop to filter in the data
        operator="AND" // Use the AND operator between keywords
        component={FilterList} // The component used to render the filter. It sets the keywords to filter with a callback passed to it's props
    />
};

export default filterDecorator({name: 'myFilter', getData: (state) => state.data })(MyComponent);
```

I want the end-user to be able to set filtering options via `Filter`'s props. For example, when filtering with keywords, I'd like to be able to set the logical operator to use (`AND` or `OR`) via a prop `operator`. The library also exports a function to retrieve the filtered data. Since this function needs to know about the options of the filter but it does not have access to props, I use redux state (the `Filter` component dispatches an action when the `operator` prop is updated).

I feel awkward about this. It doesn't feel right two have the information in 2 different places: redux's state and the props.

Are there any known patterns for this kind of situations?

Comment: Have you tried `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: @Ursus The prop is set by the end-user of the library, not by the library itself. So it's up to the end-user to use `mapStateToProps` for the `operator` prop

Comment: The props are derived from your state. The state is changed by actions that you dispatch. So the thing is that you should not change your props directly, but dispatch an action that changes the state and thereby the props. You *can* do what you want with your props, of course, but then you throw away all the benefits that come with redux' lifecycle/unidirectional architecture.